# How to load newest pmml model from python3.6.10?

Tags: java, scikit-learn, pmml

**Target:**

**1-** Train model with Python

**2-** Load model with Java

Python code:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FtGk5Jm9xz/

Java code:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sv9DZqqm5s/

pom.xml

---

```
<properties>
    <springVersion>4.1.1.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.12</log4j.version>
    <shiro.version>1.2.3</shiro.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.6</mysql.version>
    <mybatis.version>3.4.5</mybatis.version>
</properties>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml-evaluator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml-evaluator-extension</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The sentense in above java code:

```
valuator evaluator = modelEvaluatorFactory.newModelEvaluator(pmml,"model");
```

Is wrong.

I find some [hints](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorFactory/newModelEvaluator) in Google
But I can not combine the `hints` with above java code.

Could you help me?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered reading the manual?

See the "basic usage" section here: https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator#basic-usage

```
Evaluator evaluator = new LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder()
  .load(new File("model.pmml"))
  .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,when I use your code,I get `Unhandled exceptions: java.io.IOException, org.xml.sax.SAXException, javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`